# Kubernetes API returns 403 Forbidden from inside a pod with seemingly correct ClusterRole bound to pod Service Account

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Python script that runs inside a k8s pod (Google Kubernetes Engine 1.25) and queries K8S API to create VaultStaticSecret's resources.

I'll paste Helm Chart templates for brevity:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
rules:
- apiGroups: ["secrets.hashicorp.com"]
  resources: ["vaultstaticsecrets"]
  verbs: ["list", "create", "update", "patch", "watch", "get"]
- apiGroups: ["secrets.hashicorp.com"]
  resources: ["vaultstaticsecrets/status"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Looks like k8s should allow this service account to list VaultStaticSecrets, eg.:

```
kubectl auth can-i get vaultstaticsecret --as system:serviceaccount:vault-secrets-operator-system:vault-secrets-syncer
yes
```

Yet Python inside the script errors with:

```
An exception occurred when querying for VaultStaticSecret: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '26c77f88-2d10-426c-9c23-a830c8f6c50e', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '44e95fb1-2e69-4685-8a4e-26140f6145a9', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '5969f717-f4e9-4246-83b2-c6b7c9f20f49', 'Date': 'Tue, 20 Feb 2024 12:16:54 GMT', 'Content-Length': '491'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":".vaultstaticsecrets.secrets.hashicorp.com \"vaultstaticsecrets\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:vault-secrets-operator-system:vault-secrets-syncer\" cannot get resource \"/dagster\" in API group \"vaultstaticsecrets.secrets.hashicorp.com\" in the namespace \"data-platform\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"vaultstaticsecrets","group":"vaultstaticsecrets.secrets.hashicorp.com"},"code":403}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I've found that I was passing k8s namespace argument to "get_namespaced_custom_object" function with a trailing slash, yet the error didn't have trailing slash.